# Capturing Opening price at a specific time

Tags: pine-script

Good evening all,

My first post so please bear with me.

Capture price open at a certain time to replicate another time zone opening (represented by a line for the next 24 hours).

Currently using the below but that is fixed to UTC

```
dOpen = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

[Current dOpen set to security UTC][1]
I am after being able to select another time for my dOpen.

Currently have the above setup to use UTC, but am intrigued to see if I can replicate it for other time zones.

I have been reading a lot but don't seem to be able to find the right material to assist me.
Any guidance will be gratefully received.

Edit Update 29/01/2021
I have done some homework and have the below, but I think that its not as clean as it should be. I would be grateful if someone could cast their eyes over it and offer some suggestions.

```
//@version=4
study("Timed Open", overlay=true)

offset_val = input(title="Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=20)

LonOpenInput = input('0800-0801:1234567', title="London") //set the opening range you are interested in
NYOpenInput = input('1300-1301:1234567', title="New York") //set the opening range you are interested in
AsiaOpenInput = input('2300-2301:1234567', title="Asia") //set the opening range you are interested in


LonOpen = time(timeframe.period, LonOpenInput)
NYOpen = time(timeframe.period, NYOpenInput)
AsiaOpen = time(timeframe.period, AsiaOpenInput)

var LonOpenPA = 0.0
if LonOpen
    if not LonOpen[1]
        LonOpenPA := open
    else
        LonOpenPA := max(open, LonOpenPA)

var NYOpenPA = 0.0
if NYOpen
    if not NYOpen[1]
        NYOpenPA := open
    else
        NYOpenPA := max(open, NYOpenPA)

var AsiaOpenPA = 0.0
if AsiaOpen
    if not AsiaOpen[1]
        AsiaOpenPA := open
    else
        AsiaOpenPA := max(open, AsiaOpenPA)


plot(not LonOpen ? LonOpenPA : na, title="London Open", color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(LonOpenPA, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="London Open",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="London Open")

plot(not NYOpen ? NYOpenPA : na, title="New York Open", color=color.blue, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(NYOpenPA, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York Open",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York Open")


plot(not AsiaOpen ? AsiaOpenPA : na, title="Asia Open", color=color.orange, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(AsiaOpenPA, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.orange,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia Open",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia Open")
```

Edit Update 30/01/2021 @ 1400

Updated script to capture Daily and weekly market opening times and applied suggested comments from @AnyDozer

```
//@version=4
study("Help (Timed Open) - DozerAssit", overlay=true)

offset_val = input(title="Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=30)
    
LonDOpenInput = input('0800-0801:134567', title="London Daily Open") //set the opening range you are interested in
LonWOpenInput = input('0800-0801:2', title="London Weekly Open") //set the opening range you are interested in

NYDOpenInput = input('1300-1301:134567', title="New York Daily Open") //set the opening range you are interested in
NYWOpenInput = input('1300-1301:2', title="New York Weekly Open") //set the opening range you are interested in

AsiaDOpenInput = input('2300-2301:134567', title="Asia Daily Open") //set the opening range you are interested in
AsiaWOpenInput = input('2300-2301:2', title="Asia Weekly Open") //set the opening range you are interested in


LonDOpen = time("1", LonDOpenInput)
LonWOpen = time("1", LonWOpenInput)

NYDOpen = time("1", NYDOpenInput)
NYWOpen = time("1", NYWOpenInput)

AsiaDOpen = time("1", AsiaDOpenInput)
AsiaWOpen = time("1", AsiaWOpenInput)

var LonDOpenPA = 0.0
if LonDOpen
    if not LonDOpen[1]
        LonDOpenPA := open

var LonWOpenPA = 0.0
if LonWOpen
    if not LonWOpen[1]
        LonWOpenPA := open


var NYDOpenPA = 0.0
if NYDOpen
    if not NYDOpen[1]
        NYDOpenPA := open
    
var NYWOpenPA = 0.0
if NYWOpen
    if not NYWOpen[1]
        NYWOpenPA := open


var AsiaDOpenPA = 0.0
if AsiaDOpen
    if not AsiaDOpen[1]
        AsiaDOpenPA := open
    
var AsiaWOpenPA = 0.0
if AsiaWOpen
    if not AsiaWOpen[1]
        AsiaWOpenPA := open



plot(not LonDOpen ? LonDOpenPA : na, title="London D Open", color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(LonDOpenPA, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="London D Open",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="London D Open")
plot(not LonWOpen ? LonWOpenPA : na, title="London W Open", color=color.yellow, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(LonWOpenPA, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="London W Open",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="London W Open")


plot(not NYDOpen ? NYDOpenPA : na, title="New York D Open", color=color.blue, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(NYDOpenPA, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York D Open",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York D Open")
plot(not NYWOpen ? NYWOpenPA : na, title="New York W Open", color=color.blue, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(NYWOpenPA, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York W Open",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York W Open")


plot(not AsiaDOpen ? AsiaDOpenPA : na, title="Asia D Open", color=color.orange, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(AsiaDOpenPA, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.orange,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia D Open",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia D Open")
plot(not AsiaWOpen ? AsiaWOpenPA : na, title="Asia W Open", color=color.orange, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(AsiaWOpenPA, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.orange,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia W Open",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia W Open")
```

I have come across the below but am having issues implementing it (still playing),

```
onlyLastperiode = input (title="show only last periode", type=input.bool , defval=false) 
closeTime = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", time_close[0], lookahead=true)
paintitNot = timenow > (closeTime + (24*60*1000*60))
```

How to implement this to the plot ----

```
onlyLastperiode and paintitNot
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by question 1. Could you edit your question to include a chart on which you draw what you mean? As for question 2, it's not possible to access the Volume Profile parameters in Pine Script afaik. I've seen scripts that try to replicate that like [this one](https://www.tradingview.com/script/FQmVaaK9-Volume-Profile-Makit0/) or [this one](https://www.tradingview.com/script/W5N54CeR-Volume-Profile-Free-Ultra-SLI-100-Levels-Value-Area-VWAP-RRB/) for example.

Comment: Cheers @BjornMistiaen for your quick reply. I have edited my question. I hope that makes for sense.

Comment: If someone could provide direction to capturing price at a certain time, say the low of price action at 1000 or the price action at 1000 for an ema, I think I could go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the script so that it would output something. Explain what result you expect in the screenshot.

```
//@version=4
study("Help (Timed Open)", overlay=true)

offset_val = input(title="Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=20)

LonOpenInput = input('0800-0801:1234567', title="London") //set the opening range you are interested in
NYOpenInput = input('1300-1301:1234567', title="New York") //set the opening range you are interested in
AsiaOpenInput = input('2300-2301:1234567', title="Asia") //set the opening range you are interested in


LonOpen = time("1", LonOpenInput)
NYOpen = time("1", NYOpenInput)
AsiaOpen = time("1", AsiaOpenInput)

var LonOpenPA = 0.0
if LonOpen
    if not LonOpen[1]
        LonOpenPA := open
    else
        LonOpenPA := max(open, LonOpenPA)

var NYOpenPA = 0.0
if NYOpen
    if not NYOpen[1]
        NYOpenPA := open
    else
        NYOpenPA := max(open, NYOpenPA)

var AsiaOpenPA = 0.0
if AsiaOpen
    if not AsiaOpen[1]
        AsiaOpenPA := open
    else
        AsiaOpenPA := max(open, AsiaOpenPA)


plot(not LonOpen ? LonOpenPA : na, title="London Open", color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(LonOpenPA, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="London Open",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="London Open")

plot(not NYOpen ? NYOpenPA : na, title="New York Open", color=color.blue, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(NYOpenPA, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York Open",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York Open")


plot(not AsiaOpen ? AsiaOpenPA : na, title="Asia Open", color=color.orange, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(AsiaOpenPA, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.orange,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia Open",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia Open")
```

[image]

Comment: (as always thanks for the assist), for my own learning I see you made a change from "timeframe.period" to "1" please could you explain that to me.
I am also looking at doing the same for weekly(monthly, yearly) open for the time ranges and scanning over the code again I can achieve weekly by changing "input('0800-0801:1234567', title="London")" to "input('0800-0801:1', title="London")".
It just feelings like I am repeating a lot of the code.

Comment: You set a very narrow opening range of 1 minute from the point of view of finding the opening price, this is normal, but then it is necessary that the condition on the first bar is true, so I set the timeframe to "1". I do not understand why you are looking for `max`, this is unnecessary.

Comment: made adjustment as suggested and updated above. To tidy up the visual element of the script I want to able to add the option of being able to show or not show previous daily opens. I have added the scripts snippet I am playing with above to try and achieve this.